# Circe: Moving an Implicit Encoder into A Generic Class

Tags: scala, generics, types, shapeless, circe

I am working with the Circe library and want to learn the ropes. Consider the following code:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder, Json}

sealed trait Something
case class Name(val name: String) extends Something

class myClass[T](name: Option[Name] = None, data: Option[Seq[T]] = None) {
  // convert an arbitrary sequence to json
  def seqToJson[T](lst: Seq[T])(implicit encoder: Encoder[T]): Json = {
    lst.asJson
  }

  val mydata: Json = seqToJson(data.get)
}

object Trace extends App {
  val name = new myClass(Some(Name("Noob")))
}
```

Following on from the excellent answer here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304787/how-to-convert-seq-to-json-using-circe-inside-a-function-keep-getting-implici), I am now trying an example where I can build an encoder into a class.

However when I run the above code, it says:

> could not find implicit value for parameter encoder:
>   io.circe.Encoder[T] [error]   val mydata: Json = seqToJson(data.get)
>   [error]                                                   ^

Now my question is, why is this happening. When I move the definition of the implicit encoder inside the class, why can the compiler not pick up how to use it?

I tried something else too, which was to move where I define the implicit encoder:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder, Json}

sealed trait Something
case class Name(val name: String) extends Something

class myClass[T](name: Option[Name] = None, data: Option[Seq[T]] = None)(implicit encoder: Encoder[T]) {
  // convert an arbitrary sequence to json
  def seqToJson[T](lst: Seq[T]): Json = {
    lst.asJson
  }

  val mydata: Json = seqToJson(data.get)
}

object Trace extends App {
  val name = new myClass(Some(Name("Noob")))
}
```

This gives the following error:

could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Seq[T]]
ambiguous implicit values:

```
[error]  both lazy value encodeDuration in object Encoder of type io.circe.Encoder[java.time.Duration]
[error]  and lazy value encodeInstant in object Encoder of type io.circe.Encoder[java.time.Instant]
[error]  match expected type io.circe.Encoder[T]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]   val name = new myClass(Some(Name("Noob")))
```

So my question is, how would I get the encoder that is defined implicitly into scope for the Class. Any answers with an explanation of the theory would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Used Ivan's structure and it works!

```
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder, Json}

class myClass[T](data: Seq[T])(implicit encoder: Encoder[T]) {
  def seqToJson(lst: Seq[T]): Json = {
    lst.asJson
  }
}

object Trace extends App {
  println(new myClass[Int](data = Seq(1,2,3)))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my question is, why is this happening. When I move the definition
>   of the implicit encoder inside the class, why can the compiler not
>   pick up how to use it?

The answer is that there is no implicit `Encoder[T]` available in the scope of class `myClass`.

You can fix it by moving `(implicit encoder: Encoder[T])` to constructer, which you did.

Additionally, you're defining generic type `T` in two places

```
class myClass[T]
```

and

```
def seqToJson[T]
```

You should keep just one at `myClass`

> could not find implicit value for parameter encoder:
>   io.circe.Encoder[Seq[T]] ambiguous implicit values:

This is caused by the problem of missing generic type. You didn't specify the type `T` when creating a new instance of `myClass`. It will compile if you do it.

For example,

```
val name = new myClass[Int](Some(Name("Noob")))
```

This will fail during runtime on line `seqToJson(data.get)` because you're not passing in any `data`.

> how would I get the encoder that is defined implicitly into scope for
>   the Class

Constructor is a good option

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I added an edit where I try to code my interpretation of what you have said. For some reason compilation fails again. Is there a way around it?

Comment: you didn't remove `T` from `def seqToJson[T]`. It's mentioned in my answer

Comment: Ahh I see now, thanks Ivan it works - looks like Scala will take many moons to get the hang of

Comment: One question I had was is it possible to use the Any type, instead of a generic type T? It doesn't compile in that case but I am sure there must be a way around that

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve. When using implicit `Encoder[T]`, compiler must know type `T` in advance so it can pick correct encoder from implicit context. If you say `Any`, it causes ambiguity.

Comment: thanks - may be a design issue on my end. I will take another look to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simplified snippet

```
def f[T](v: Option[T] = None) = v
f() // T is inferred as Nothing
```

Here type parameter `T` is inferred as `Nothing` because `None` is defined as

```
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Hence in the following situation

```
def f[T](v: Option[T] = None)(implicit ev: Encoder[T]) = v
f() // error because requiring Encoder[Nothing] capability
```

we actually request `Encoder[Nothing]` which errors. In fact, you can simulate similar error by simply requesting

```
implicitly[Encoder[Nothing]]
```

which errors with

```
Error: diverging implicit expansion for type io.circe.Encoder[Nothing]
starting with lazy value encodeZoneOffset in object Encoder
```

Not sure why specifically it mentions `encodeZoneOffset` but it could be related to how implicit search works and `encodeZoneOffset` is the [last](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/6d6f70e5cc3f9456bfee95a5818008142f569967/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Encoder.scala#L691) implicit value in `Encoder` companion.